# SQL Azure database slowness on one Schema

Tags: sql-server

We are seeing queries take a LONG time from one of our schemas in our Azure database.

We've reset the app, scaled down the DB and back up, removed some data that was inputted around the time the issue started.

Other parts of the application are running fine, but they are totally on a different schema.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Schemas in SQL Server are a logical construct and shouldn't have any effect on query performance. Troubleshoot it like any other slow query (which is to say, look at the query plan and see if there is anything that can be optimized).

Comment: @BenThul: We have it back up and working. It was a record that stores `nvarchar(max)` in the database. We aren't sure if it was because it was too long (not sure if that is possible) or if there was a special character in there. We will continue to research and I'll try to update the post later. We deleted that record item with the column and the website immediately responded perfectly after that.

Comment: It sounds like you've diagnosed your issue, anything else is going to require the actual query, sample data, table schemas and the actual execution plan ([PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan))